# GLSL array is not passing through data

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, web-audio-api

I am currently working on GLSL shader that passes through a 256 length array of ints that is pulled from audio. I am using Javascript and Three.js to do the actual rendering. I get the audio object later in the script by first defining a list of uniforms:

```
uniforms1 = {
    time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
    resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
    mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
    audio:{ type: "int", value: new Array(256) },
};
```

Each rendering frame, I am calling the following:

```
freqByteData = new Uint8Array(audio.analyser.frequencyBinCount); 
audio.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);
uniforms1.audio.value = freqByteData;
```

Where audio.analyser is a web audio analyser node. This part of the code works fine, and I have verified that uniforms1.audio is an Uint8Array populated with the analyser data. The issue I am having is that I can't seem to pull this data into the fragment shader itself. I am very new to GLSL, so I am assuming it is a basic problem, but I have spent some time looking around for a solution and cannot seem to find one. Below is the fragment shader code:

```
<script id="fragment_shader2" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

        uniform vec2 resolution;
        uniform float time;
        uniform vec2 mouse;
        uniform int audio[256];

        #define N 100
        void main( void ) {

            vec2 v = (gl_FragCoord.xy - resolution) / min(resolution.y,resolution.x) *0.5;

            float pi2 = 3.1415926535 * 2.0;
            float C = cos(mouse.x * pi2);
            float S = sin(mouse.y * pi2);
            //C = v.x;
            //S = v.y;

            float a = float(audio[20]/100);
            for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
                float x = v.x*v.x - v.y*v.y + C;
                float y = v.y * v.x + v.x * v.y+ S;
                v = vec2(x,y);
            }

            float col = v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y;

            gl_FragColor = vec4( a, sin(col*3.0), (cos(col)+sin(col))/2.0, 1.0 );

        }
    </script>
```

This creates a typical 'Julia Set' explorer, with only blues and greens, which makes sense when there is no audio playing, however, I would expect that when audio starts playing, the float 'a' would be non-zero, and therefore red would be introduced to the set. That being said, throughout the entirety of the audio, no red is visible ( even though I have also checked to make sure that audio[20] is indeed non-zero.

Again, I am a complete novice at GLSL, so I am sorry if the problem is painfully obvious, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
Isaac

Comment: Try `float a = float( audio[20] ) / 100.0;`

Comment: type `int` does not exist for uniforms, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types. Use `iv1` instead

Comment: @WestLangley This worked, and gave me no errors! however it still does not seem to be giving me anything but '0' in the last line, where I am calling 'a' in the FragColor vec4

Comment: @WestLangley I have added in a line stating if(a == 0.0){ a = 1.0;} which always returns a = 1.0; This makes sense before the music has started, however as soon as the music starts, a should no longer == 0.0 Is this simply a problem with my understanding of uniforms?

Comment: @Popov I have changed the 'Uniforms' so that the "audio" section is audio:{ type: "iv1", value: new Array(256) }, (as is done in wiki page you sent over: "uIntArray"  : { type: "iv1", value: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] },  )  however, this now gives me a 'Type Error' in the console. I assume this is partially because I have not changed the line in the actual shader which says " uniform int audio[256]; " , however in the wiki it also says that an array should look as follows: " uniform int uIntArray[ 5 ]; ", which I *believe* is what I am doing. Is there an additional step I am missing?

Comment: I expect the GPU is expecting an array of 32-bit ints. You appear to be passing in an array of 8-bit unsigned ints. Try to get it working with a hardwired audio data array first.

Comment: @WestLangley I have changed the to uniform in the audio to: audio:{ type: "iv1", value: [1000,300,400,400,300,100,500,600,400,800] }  Doing makes the a work, so I think your suggestion was exactly right (again). Will I need to convert the 8-bit unsigned ints to 32-bit ints before passing it into the glsl shader? I assume that this is what I will need to do because the web audio api requires a Uint8Array for the getFrequencyBitData method.

Comment: I was planning on just looping through this first array, and passing them into a second array that was not using 32-bit ints. I feel like this is not the best way to do it, so if you have any other ideas, please let me know!